# affine transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors (v1, v2) making angle theta1 and theta2 with the positive x-axis of the standard Cartesian coordinate system such that theta1>theta2. Is it possible that the affine transformed vectors Av1, Av2 have angles theta2 and theta3 respectively such that theta3>theta2.

My aim is to show that the vectors Av1 and Av2 will be in the same angular order as v1 and v2 such that theta2>theta3. By what argument can I show that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't true. Any transformation that reverses orientation will reverse "angle ordering".

Think of the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Reflecting in the $y$-axis sends them to $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

An affine transformtion is of the form $x \mapsto Ax+b$, where $A$ is a matrix and $b$ a vector. If $\det(A)<0$ then the transformation reverse orientation.

Comment: Hi Fly by Night. Thanks a lot for that explanation. I later realized reflection will reverse the order. But it seems apart from reflection, other transformation like scaling, rotation, shear, etc. will not change the ordering. Is that true?

Comment: @MohammadNaeem That's right. Don't forget to up-vote answers that you have found useful by clicking the up-arrow.

Comment: @FlybyNight:Could you explain why we use affine transformations in computer graphics?Why couldn't we use vector transformations?Is there anything relevant in using affine transformation other than the fact that affine spaces has no origin?

Comment: @justin Affine transformations can be used for changes of perspective. Put a coffee cup on the table and look at it from directly above. The rim will look like a perfect circle. Now sit down on a chair and look at the same rim. From your new perspective it will look like an ellipse (a squashed circle). The image of the rim on your retina has undergone an affine transformation. Affine (and projective) transformation give the impression of changing your perspective.

Comment: @FlybyNight:Thanks for your comment.But could you say by which affine transformation the rim of coffee cup turned into ellipse.I'm really asking is it by rotation,translation or any other.Also do we use affine combinations in computer graphics?

Comment: @justin Rotations and translations are Euclidean transformations. Euclidean transformations preserve lengths, angles and areas. They are simply rigid motions. You need much more, like dilations and sheer transformations to model changes of perspective. There is a whole hierarchy of transformations: Euclidean transformations, special affine, general affine and projective transformations. I suggest you make a google search. I can't explain it in a 500 character post.